# I keep getting undefined function apache_get_modules() on IIS running PHP as cgi

Tags: apache, iis, windows-server-2016, apache-modules

Is there anyway to get apache_get_modules() function working on IIS runnig PHP as a cgi?

Comment: IIS is not Apache.

Comment: Right but is there an equivalent?